# Plants vs. Zombies simulator

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, simulation

I am making a pvz simulator. We have a game board with 1 = peashooter and 2 = zombie:

```
[[(1, <__main__.Plant object at 0x0000011F0FDDA4C0>), (2, <__main__.Zombie object at 0x0000011F0F73D100>), 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

When the peashooter object shoots a pea ten times, the zombie is defeated and disappears. If they are not in the same row or the peashooter is in front of the zombie, the pea has no effect on that particular zombie.

My code:

```py
class Object:
    def __init__(self, objtype, row, column, name=None):
        self.pos = self.row, self.column = row, column
        self.name = name
        self.setup = setup
        setup[row][column] = (objtype, self)


class Plant(Object):
    def __init__(self,row, column, name=None, aoe=1, damage=1):
        super().__init__(1, row, column, name)
        self.aoe = aoe
        self.damage = damage

    def shoot(self):
        location = self.setup[self.row][self.column]
        curr_column = self.column
        while True:
            try:
                if location[0] == 2:  # zombie
                    location[1].hit(self)
                    return
            except IndexError:
                pass

            try:
                location = self.setup[self.row][curr_column]
            except IndexError:
                return
            curr_column += 1


class PlantTypes:
    @staticmethod
    def peashooter(row, column, name=None):
        return Plant(row, column, name)


class Zombie(Object):
    def __init__(self, row, column, name=None, health=10):
        super().__init__(2, row, column, name)
        self.health = health

    def hit(self, plant):
        self.health -= plant.damage
        if self.health <= 0:
            setup[self.row][self.column] = 0


class ZombieTypes:
    @staticmethod
    def basezombie(row, column, name=None):
        return Zombie(row, column, name)


setup = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

p0 = PlantTypes.peashooter(0, 0)
z0 = ZombieTypes.basezombie(0, 1)
print(setup)
for i in range(10):
    p0.shoot()

print(setup)
```

Any suggestions for readability/performance/other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shoot` is currently a method on the `Plant`, but I think this is a mis-allocation of responsibility. The majority of the work in that function is on the grid instead of on the plant. Consider making a grid class, and obligating it with collision work such as shots.

Similarly, having a zombie delete itself from the grid on death (re-death?) is a mis-allocation of responsibility.

The `objtype` integer is inconvenient to work with and inadequately constrained. Consider just keeping bare references to the object instances instead of type-object tuples in your grid.

Catching `IndexError` is a code smell and an indication of an incorrect algorithm. This can be avoided with proper iteration.

Your plant and zombie type classes are redundant and can be deleted.

0 as a default entry in your grid doesn't make much sense since you expect all entries to be type-object pairs. A single `None` would make more sense when the grid is to contain object references only.

Consider adding pretty-print methods to your classes.

### Suggested

```py
from numbers import Real
from typing import Optional


class Object:
    def __init__(self, row: int, column: int, name: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        self.row, self.column = row, column
        self.name = name


class Plant(Object):
    def __init__(self, row: int, column: int, name: Optional[str] = None, aoe: Real = 1, damage: Real = 1) -> None:
        super().__init__(row, column, name)
        self.aoe = aoe
        self.damage = damage

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name[:3] if self.name else 'pla'


class Zombie(Object):
    def __init__(self, row: int, column: int, name: Optional[str] = None, health: Real = 10) -> None:
        super().__init__(row, column, name)
        self.health = health

    def hit(self, damage: Real) -> None:
        self.health -= damage

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'Z{self.health:2d}'


class Grid:
    def __init__(self, m: int, n: int) -> None:
        self.m, self.n = m, n
        self.grid: list[list[Optional[Object]]] = [
            [None]*n
            for _ in range(m)
        ]

    def add(self, obj: Object) -> None:
        self.grid[obj.row][obj.column] = obj

    def shoot(self, plant: Plant) -> None:
        row = self.grid[plant.row]
        for col in range(1+plant.column, self.n):
            zombie = row[col]
            if isinstance(zombie, Zombie):
                zombie.hit(plant.damage)
                if zombie.health <= 0:
                    row[col] = None
                break

    def describe(self) -> str:
        return '\n'.join(
            ' '.join(
                f'{str(o):3s}' if o else ' . '
                for o in row
            )
            for row in self.grid
        )


def main() -> None:
    grid = Grid(m=3, n=4)

    p0 = Plant(row=0, column=0, name='peashooter')
    z0 = Zombie(row=0, column=1, name='basezombie')
    grid.add(p0)
    grid.add(z0)
    print(grid.describe())

    for _ in range(10):
        grid.shoot(p0)

    print()
    print(grid.describe())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
pea Z10  .   . 
 .   .   .   . 
 .   .   .   . 

pea  .   .   . 
 .   .   .   . 
 .   .   .   .
```

Comment: I would prefer the plant shoot to the right.

Comment: @Reinderin The output still shows shooting up-to-down.

Comment: @BgilMidol Really? The output shows that the zombie to the side disappears.

Comment: ooppss..........

Comment: How would I take the aoe into effect? For example, threepeater shoots in three rows.

Comment: Add another dimension to your loop so that you check three rows for every column.

Comment: no, threepeater shoots a pea in it's row, the row above it, and the row below it. If there is not enough space, the pea has no effect.

Comment: It sounds like you already know the intended behaviour, so have fun coding. But discussion about how to do it here is off-topic.